# Can I copy my AutoML models from one project to another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl

I have my trained AutoML models in my current GCP project, but I want to copy some of them into another project. Is that possible in GCP, or do I have to create a new AutoML model in my new project with the same dataset and train it again, so I get a copy of the one I have in the other project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to transfer between projects as per the offical documentation..
 "Unless otherwise specified in applicable terms of service or documentation, custom models created in Cloud AutoML products cannot be exported"

You can review the documentation here [1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/models)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suspected that, but I wanted to make sure by asking here.